# How to access element in a multidimensional array using PHP5

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and I am trying to access the bolded element in the following code. What is the most appropriate way to do this?

```
Array
   (
     [hash] => f576eb071486e32a0a3af2e47e8983f9
     [thumb_exists] =>
     [bytes] => 0
     [path] => /
      [is_dir] => 1
      [size] => 0 bytes
      [root] => app_folder
      [contents] => Array
        (
         [0] => Array
            (
                [revision] => 2
                [rev] => 20def95ea
                [thumb_exists] =>
                [bytes] => 354
                [modified] => Sun, 17 Feb 2013 02:06:27 +0000
                [client_mtime] => Sun, 17 Feb 2013 02:06:27 +0000
                [path] => **/working-draft.txt**
                [is_dir] =>
                [icon] => page_white_text
                [root] => dropbox
                [mime_type] => text/plain
                [size] => 354 bytes
            )

    )

    [icon] => folder
  )
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
  $l = $array['contents']['path'];
  echo $l;
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks
D.

Comment: $array['contents'][0]['path'];

Comment: `$array['contents'][0]['path']`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Please add this as an answer to accept it.

Comment: Whats your problem attacking this question? Is there a duplicate or you just find it too simple? And if its simple why is this bad? Its not like I haven't tried to figure the answer.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess people downvote because you could have probably figured this out on your own without much effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like this

```
$array['contents'][0]['path'];
```